# Protocol buffers - only generating OuterClasses

Tags: protocol-buffers, protoc

I am trying to generate java source files from several proto files.

Im using Ubuntu 17.04.

I use the following shell script to do this:

```
for i in ./src/main/proto/my-protos; do
    [ -f "$i" ] || break
    protoc -I= ./src/main/proto/my-protos/ --java_out=./src/main/java/my/java/project ./$i  2>&1
done
```

I have also tried the following, where I specify the `protoc-gen-grpc-java` plugin:

```
protoc --plugin=./target/protoc-plugins/protoc-gen-grpc-java-1.4.0-linux-x86_64.exe --proto_path=./src/main/proto/my-protos/ --java_out=./src/main/java ./src/main/proto/my-protos/*.proto
```

In both cases the result is the same.

The problem is, these commands only generating XXXOuterClass.java files. There are no service classes, messages or stubs generated.

How can I generate all java classes using `protoc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

Use the **protoc-jar-maven-plugin** - see https://github.com/os72/protoc-jar-maven-plugin/issues/47